# ReactJS - useState updates value in top-level component but component doesn't re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, use-state

So I have a component that has a 'posts' variable passed in, which is managed by useState, and inside my App component I have some child components which use that variable:

```
function App() {

    const [posts, updatePosts] = useState([
        {
            title: "Cut the Grass",
            description: "Get it done before 4pm",
        },
        {
            title: "Purchase LOTR: DVD box set",
            description: "Extended Edition."
        }
    ])

    return (
        <div>
            <UserBar loggedInFlag = {userIsLoggedIn}/>
            <br /><br /><hr /><br />

            <CreateTodo todoList={posts} updatePosts = { () => updatePosts } />
            <input type="submit" value="test" onClick={() => console.log(posts)}/>
            <TodoList items={posts}/>

        </div>
    )
}
export default App;
```

There is logic inside my CreateTodo component that grabs fields for a new post, adds it to the `posts` array, and successfully updates the `posts` variable; I can test this with my "test" button on the second line there, which always prints out the correct todo list to the console, and it contains my new post. So this shows me that the update of `posts` inside the `<CreateTodo>` bubbles up to my App component just fine.

However, the `<TodoList >` component, which uses the same `posts` variable as above, does not re-render when the variable is updated. That component only displays the todolist (with the new value) when I change some code in the IDE, save, and then the page refreshes with the new list. **How do I fix my useState so that whenever the `post` value is updated, it will automatically rerender the `<TodoList >` component?**

For reference, here is how that component looks.

```
export default function TodoList({ items}) {
    
    return (
        <div>
            {items.map( (todo, i) => <Todo {...todo} title={todo.title} description={todo.description} key={'post-' + i} />)}
        </div> 
    )
```

and, here is how the CreateTodo component looks:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function CreateTodo ({todoList, updatePosts}) {
     return (
          <form onSubmit={e => e.preventDefault()} style={{borderStyle:"solid"}}>

             <div>
                 <br/>
                 <label htmlFor="create-title">Title:</label>
                 <br/>
                 <input type="text" id="create-title" />

                 <br/>
                 <label htmlFor="create-title">Description (optional):</label>
                 <br/>
                 <input type="text" id="create-description" />
                 <br/>

                 <br/>
             </div>

             <input type="submit" value="Create" onClick={() => addTodo({todoList, updatePosts})}/>
         </form>   
          )
 }
 

 function addTodo({todoList, updatePosts}){
    let newTodo = {
        title : document.getElementById("create-title").value,
        description : document.getElementById("create-description").value,
        dateCreated : Date.now(),
        completed : false,
        dateCompleted : null
    }

    todoList.push(newTodo);
    updatePosts(todoList);

    document.getElementById("create-title").value = "";
    document.getElementById("create-description").value = "";

    // alert(`"${newTodo.title}" has been added to list`);
 }
```

Comment: Can you share the content of the `CreateTodo` component to see how you update the posts?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yep, as I mentioned the updatePosts that is passed into <CreateTodo> is called inside that component. I'll update the question to include the code from that component for some more background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to pass the `updatePosts` function directly to your component:

```
<CreateTodo todoList={posts} updatePosts={updatePosts} />
```

Second, in your `addTodo` function, you're mutating the state object directly:

```
// Don't do this
todoList.push(newTodo);
```

All you need to do is to call `updatePosts` with the updated list:

```
updatePosts([
  ...todoList,
  newTodo,
]);
```

Comment: Thank you, looks like this works. Could you explain why 
`updatePosts(todoList);`
doesn't work but your approach does? This is the part that confused me

Comment: You shouldn't mutate the state object directly. Which you did by using the `.push` method. Because React needs to know when you update your states to rerender your component. That's why you need to use the `updatePosts` function provided and pass the new state as argument. Which in this case the new state is a new list containing your old list plus a new member.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add () in the updatePosts prop

updatePosts={() => updatePosts()} or just
updatePosts={updatePosts}